# Is there a comment system for blogging site that does not require javascript?

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, blogs

I have been looking for a proper comment system for my blogging site. I built my blog engine from scratch using php and mysql and do not use wordpress, joomla, or anything like it. I want the comment system to be functional even if a user has javascript disabled.

I was previously looking at Disqus, but it turns out that I am required to embed some javascript files produced by Disqus in my existing code, which I assume means that the comment section will be unavailable if javascript is turned off. It looks like some other websites that use Disqus have this problem when javascript is turned off.

Is it common nowadays to ignore users who turn off javascript/non-tech-savvy people who do not know how to turn javascript on?

Comment: Just curious, what group of people have to actively turn their JS on?!

Comment: The average person doesn't know how to turn JavaScript *off*.

Comment: @Shad: Those who have had someone else turn it off :-P

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I understand your trepidation, but I've slapped together a commenting system on my own also. Even got threaded comments to work. Really, it's just a matter of filling a `form` with username, email and the comment, then assigning it a timestamp and ID in your database. For spam protection you can use:

- [OpenID](http://openid.net/), which of course has other benefits
- stuff like [Akismet](http://akismet.com/), which filters the data posted
- captchas as a last resort

The biggest difficulty with commenting is not the format, it's the spam.

Answer (score 1):

Well, why not roll out your custom comment system? After all, you've created your own custom blog engine :).

**OR**

Use [phpBB](http://www.phpbb.com/community/viewtopic.php?f=46&t=2106245)

Comment: I knew at some point somebody will suggest something like that. I would like to use pre-existing system for commenting. I think there's a lot of things I need to care about if I write it myself; Login account, admin stuff, spam protector, and then i need to create extra space to store the comments in my database. I feel I have achieved what I wanted (building my own blog engine)..commenting is just an additional part

Answer (score 0):

It can be done very easily really, you just have to use good ol' form posts ...

http://www.javascript-coder.com/html-form/html-form-tutorial-p1.phtml

Now it won't be as sexy without javascript but it'll get the job done.